# Why is this error, GraphQL query is unauthorized showing up in facebook Erro?

Tags: facebook, graphql, messenger, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

[image]

I tried to open a facebook messenger and it gives me that error.  What is the issue can anyone face the same issue that I have been facing, I think it comes from fb side but dont know much about it right now, anyone can help me to find the issue for this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this error, GraphQL query is unauthorized showing up in facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77341048/why-is-this-error-graphql-query-is-unauthorized-showing-up-in-facebook)

Comment: No. There is no answer from facebook. I dont know what is the issue,